# What is the best way to pass a string containing a pdf name in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

(I am a newbie on Objective-C, and) I have been trying to pass a pdf name and initialize a class like this:

```
contCon = [[contentController alloc] initwithPdf:@"mag.pdf"];
```

and

```
-(id)initwithPdf:(NSString *)pdfName{ ... }
```

it gave me no error but pdf name doesn't come up as I sent it. So i tried to do this:

```
contCon = [[contentController alloc] initwithPdf:CFSTR("mag.pdf")];
```

I also couldn't figure ou how to get this type of data in the method.

```
-(id)initwithPdf:(CFSTR)pdfName
```

or

```
-(id)initwithPdf:(CFSTR *)pdfName
```

doesn't seem to work, and google didn't help me either.

I want to know in what type to pass the name of the pdf file. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What on earth does "doesn't come up as i sent it" mean?

Comment: Are you filling in the full path from within the body of your method?

Comment: when I set a breakpoint inside "-(id)initwithPdf:(NSString *)pdfName{ ... }", the pdfName is an upside down question mark instead of a "mag.pdf" string.

Comment: Abizem I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Ignoring the style of names, there's nothing seemingly wrong with the first 'init...` method call - you're problem is somewhere else - more info / context required for someone to help you. Also, try to narrow the problem to one issue.

Comment: You're right about passing it as an argument. Id' use the `NSString` type that you're using in the 2nd code sample. Put a line of code in that `initWithPDF:(NSString *)pdfName` method as follows:

`NSLog(@"PDF Name Argument = %@", pdfName);`

And tell us what the output is.

Comment: Alright I thought I was using the data types incorrectly. I will look into the problem somewhere else in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
contCon = [[contentController alloc] initwithPdf:@"mag.pdf"];
```

and

```
-(id)initwithPdf:(NSString *)pdfName{ ... }
```

is better one......

Answer (score 0):

Your first method is the right one.  And what does "it doesn't come up" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you pass the whole filepath of the pdf,rather than just the pdfName??

Define : **"pdf name doesn't come up as I sent it"**